# Why can't my brother play my copy of Call of Duty: Ghosts after a system transfer?

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-ghosts

My Xbox 360 broke. I have Call of Duty: Ghosts on my Live account.

I bought another Xbox 360 and downloaded it to my new Xbox 360. I have a brother who also has an account on my new Xbox 360 (as he did with my other Xbox). On my old Xbox he could go on his account and play Ghosts, but on the new Xbox only I can access it.

Why is that, and is there any way it will work again?

Answer (score 9):

Content on the Xbox Live marketplace is tied to both the console and profile. If you get a new console, the licensing is still tied to the old console and therefore certain restrictions are in place.

What you need to do is transfer the license, [per Microsoft's FAQ](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/downloadable-content/download-content#92889200c6a1493086c0d5ec574a93da):

> If you’ve recently repaired your console, or if you’ve purchased a new
>   console, use the license transfer option on your console to transfer
>   content licenses. Here’s how:
>
> - On your console, sign in to Xbox Live using the gamertag that you used
>     to purchase the content.
>
>   - Need to find your Microsoft account and/or
>       password? See [Find your Microsoft account email address or password](http://support.xbox.com/my-account/microsoft-account/forgot-microsoft-account).
> - Go to settings and select Account.
>
> [image]
>
> - Under Your **Billing Options**, select **License Transfer**.
> - Follow the instructions to transfer the
>     content licenses.
> - After transferring the licenses, you need to
>     download the content again to update the local licenses. For
>     information about how to do this, see [How to redownload previously
>     downloaded or purchased content to your Xbox 360](http://support.xbox.com/xbox-360/downloadable-content/redownload-content).
>
> After you follow these steps, other profiles can use content on your console and when
>   you’re not connected to Xbox Live.

Comment: One limitation to this is that you can only transfer your licenses once every four months. I assume to keep people from abusing it.